# Entity Framework Core - EntityTypeBuilder Derivated class with overload of Property

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-core

I have 2 entities (BEntity and CBEntity ) that share some of their properties.
They use respectively B & C model
In one case, the property is optional but not in the other.

I want to know if I can use inheritance in this case (from A)

Mapping abstract (A):

```
internal class AEntityBaseMapping<TAEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TABaseEntity>
    where TABaseEntity: TABase
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TABaseEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.Width)
            .HasColumnName("SizeWidth");

        builder.Property(x => x.Height)
            .HasColumnName("SizeHeight");

        builder.Property(x => x.X)
            .HasColumnName("PositionX");
        builder.Property(x => x.Y)
            .HasColumnName("PositionY");
    }
}
```

Mapping Entity B (optional arg)

```
internal class BEntityMapping :AEntityBaseMapping<BEntity, B>
{

    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BEntity> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        builder.ToTable("B", "B",
            tb => tb.IsTemporalTable()
        );
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasColumnName("BId");

        builder.Property(x => x.UserId)
            .HasColumnName("UserId")
            .IsRequired();

    }
}
```

Mapping Entity C (required arg)

```
internal class CEntityMapping :AEntityBaseMapping<CEntity, C>
{

    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CEntity> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);

        builder.ToTable("C", "C",
            tb => tb.IsTemporalTable()
        );
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasColumnName("CId");

        builder.Property(x => x.quality)
            .HasColumnName("Quality")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
//how to add isRequired on x.Width, x.Height, x.X and x.Y to add
```